# Passing data without props on a functionnal component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

*Hello guys,*

I'm relatively new to **react hooks,** and back in my time(one year ago), when I was passing props through
component, I would then use them with **"props.something."**

Now I have done a "todo list" and I can use my props in another way, by referencing the props in an objet in parameter :

**const Form = ({ addTodo }) => {
   addTodo(x)
}**

What is that ? Why we don't use **this.props anymore,** why the **object** in parameter ? Is the old way passing props **dead** ? Is this because of react **Hooks** ?

*To illustrate more my exemple here the two component talking to eachother.*

The first one :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Form from './Form';


const Affichage = () => {

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4'
    ])

    const addTodo = text => {
        const newTodos = [...todos, text];
        setTodos(newTodos)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Form addTodo={addTodo} />
            <ul>
                {todos.map((item, index) =>{
                    return(
                        <li key={index}>
                            {item}
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Affichage;`
```

The second one :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';


const Form = ({ addTodo }) => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(value);
        addTodo(value);

    }


    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            <input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
            <button>Envoyer</button>

        </form>
    )

}

export default Form;
```

If someone passing by could enlight me it would awesome ☺

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing changed. It's just a shortcut for `destructuring`

```
const Component = props =>{
    const { foo } = props
}
```

Is the equivalent of

```
const Component = ({ foo }) =>{

}
```

Comment: Oh I see ! I feel stupid now lol, thank's for the response dude.